# Eslint rule for linebreaks in function bodies

Tags: eslint, eslintrc

I am looking for a rule which will mark the following as **error**:

```js
const setStuff = () => { setThing(2); setOtherThing(3); };
```

I want to enfore a linebreak when there is multiple statements in the body, so this should be correct:

```js
const setStuff = () => {
    setThing(2);
    setOtherThing(3);
};
```

Which rules is applicable for this? I can't seem to find one. I do want to keep allowing one liners for returns (e.g. `const get = () => 3`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs: [brace-style](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/brace-style)

You can use it in your `.eslintrc` like this:

```
'rules': {
    'brace-style': [
        'error',
        '1tbs'
    ]
}
```

Comment: This is a rule regarding the input arguments, not regarding the function body.

Comment: Yip, that's it! Thanks!